# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vue-router, vue-cli

I use Vue 2 in CLI mode with webpack-simple. I have following files:

main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Routes from './routes';
    
Vue.use('VueRouter');
    
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: Routes,
});
    
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router: router,
});
```

App.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
import Loader from './Loader.vue';
    
export default {
  name: 'app',
}
</script>
    
<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

routes.js:

```js
import Game from './components/Game.vue';
import Login from './components/Login.vue';
    
export default [
  { path: '/', component: Game, name: "Game" },
  { path: '/login', component: Login, name: "Login" },
]
```

Game.vue and Login.vue looks the same:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    Game
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
  name: 'game',
}
</script>
    
<style lang="scss">
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
```

unfortunately starting a file gives me an error:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register
> the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
> provide the "name" option.

Also router-view tag is not changed to proper html. I use vue router for the first time. It' been installed via npm in version 3.0.1

Any advice?

Comment: The reason was Vue.use('VueRouter') instead of Vue.use(VueRouter)

Comment: Change: Vue.use('VueRouter') ->To: Vue.use(VueRouter)

Answer (score 47):

You need to do the following:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
    
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

Ref: https://router.vuejs.org/en/installation.html

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router: router,
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: I tried your answer and it works only if you put just "router" instead of "router: router"

Answer (score 6):

Change:

```js
Vue.use('VueRouter');
```

To:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

Comment: We don't need another duplicate answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50963242/823321

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if its related to your problem or not but you have to use the VueRouter variable "Vue.use(VueRouter)" not a string "Vue.use('VueRouter')";

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, running the commands below fixed it for me.

```
npm install
npm install vue-router
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar issue while working with Vue js and laravel.
Running these commands below solved it:

```
npm install vue-router
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is occurring due to you are passing the `vue-router` as string in your example.

Use this instead:

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
```

and then register it using Vue.use() like this :

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

and as you are using es6 style import, you can also use es6 style object shorthand for router.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: Routes,
});
    
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure before creating routes and using the `VueRouter` you need to tell `Vue.js` that you are using `VueRouter`. Try this before using the `VueRouter`:

```
 import Vue from "vue";
 import VueRouter from "vue-router";
 Vue.use(VueRouter);
 .....
 const routes = [{
      path: '/', component: Home, name: "Home"
     ......
 }]
```

**Good Luck**