# how to fix Unknown custom element: <router-view>

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I import the vue-route to my app.js in my laravel vue website. Sadly, there's an error. Can you please guide me thanks

[image]

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

let routes = [
    {path: '/', component: require('./components/Welcome.vue') }

]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',   
   routes
   })



const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
});
```

master.blade.php

```
   <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
    <div id="app">

        @yield('content')

    </div>
</body
```

welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<router-view></router-view>
<vue-progress-bar> </vue-progress-bar>
@endsection
```

The result should be the Welcome.vue will display.

Comment: try  to put the router on top of your el property

Comment: It still has an error, sir @pinoyCoder

Answer (score 0):

If you use a newer version of Vue.js you should have `.default` to `require('./components/Welcome.vue')`

So line 5 would look like this

```
    {path: '/', component: require('./components/Welcome.vue').default }
```

[Stack Overflow: Why need default after require() method in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215705/why-need-default-after-require-method-in-vue)

Comment: It still has an error, sir. Is there something wrong of my import vue-router?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript), you should inject `router` option to make your whole app router aware.

So you should have something like this:

```
const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

I think this is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438605/vue-warn-unknown-custom-element-router-view-did-you-register-the-compone).